# Zend framework with GWT?

Tags: php, zend-framework, gwt

I have been experimenting with GWT recently and I really like it and would like to use it. Problem is I don't use Java on the server side, but PHP Zend Framework.

Google shows up nothing, so I am asking here - is anyone using the two together, what are the best practices (ProtocolBuffers, gwt rpc...). Is it possible at all with current state of affairs? Am I mad for wanting to do this?

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood your question. I've deleted my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not impossible - except that the default RPC implementation only works with java, so you might either have to write your own javascript overlay objects and have the serverside return json, OR use a 3rd party library like this http://code.google.com/p/gwt-hermes/ for RPC.

The UI side has nothing to do with the RPC subsystem, so you're good to go there.

Edit: after a few seconds of googling, there are a few 3rd party libs that help you do RPC with PHP backends (which essentially means using json as the protocol): http://code.google.com/p/lacertae/ and http://code.google.com/p/gwtphp/